# Stability of the solution y=0 of the differential equation $y'=y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes

I have to discuss the stability of the solution $y(t)=0$ of the nonlinear differential equation $y'=y^2$.
y is increasing irrespective of the sign of the initial condition $y(0)$ because the RHS of the differential equation is $y^2$. When $y(0)$ is negative as t approaches infinity, it seems the solutions are approaching $y-0$. But on the other hand, $y(0)>0$, the solutions are going away from $y=0$.
I think the solution is unstable. But not sure. Can someone share their ideas?

Comment: Yes, your analysis is correct. This behavior is called semi-stable, stable to one side, unstable to the other.

Comment: @AiswaryaT: You can also draw a direction field plot and see the global semi-stable behavior.

Comment: @LutzLehmann ok; I am currently referring to Nonlinear ordinary differential equations by R.Grimshaw, I couldn't  find the definition of such a kind of stability there, that's why I called the solution Unstable. In this context can I call it unstable

Comment: @Moo I drew that, and from that, I said that the solution behaves as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: If you embed it into a family $y'=y^2+a$, then the case $a=0$ corresponds to a fold point where a stable and an unstable branch for $a<0$ annihilate for $a>0$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, I am not very familiar with the terms fold point and stable and unstable branches. Can you give me the reference to read more on these?

Comment: Maybe have a look at: http://mathonline.wikidot.com/stable-semi-stable-and-unstable-equilibrium-solutions#:~:text=An%20equilibrium%20solution%20is%20said%20to%20be%20Semi%2DStable%20if,diverge%20from%20this%20equilibrium%20solution or https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/equilibriumsolutions.aspx

Comment: This are words from bifurcation theory, loosely the qualitative geometry of phase portraits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly not stable. Given $\varepsilon > 0$, the unique solution (Picard-Lindelöf Theorem) to
$$
y'=y^2, \quad y(0)=\varepsilon
$$
is given by
$$
y(t) = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}-t}.
$$
this does not even exist on $[0, \infty)$, so we can not talk about stabilty. It even explodes in finite time.

On the other hand, take $\delta <0$ and let $y$ be the solution to
$$
y' = y^2, \quad y(0)=\delta.
$$
There is a qualitative argument as to why $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} y(t) = 0$. Because of uniqueness, $y(t)$ can not cross $0$, so it stays negative. Also, it is always increasing because of $y' = y^2\geq 0$. Hence, a solution for every $t \geq 0$ exists and $\ell := \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} y(t)$ exists, too. Assume that $\ell < 0$.
In that case, $y$ stays in $[\delta, \ell]$. Moreover:
$$
y(t) = \delta + \int^t_0 y(s)^2~\mathrm{d}s \geq \delta + \int^t_0 \ell^2~\mathrm{d}s = \delta + t \ell^2
$$
So:
$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} y(t) \geq \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \delta + t\ell^2 = \infty
$$
Contradiction, and therefore $\ell = 0$.